# Get nearest neighbor point from a table closest to the point in a given row of another table

Tags: postgresql, postgis, nearest-neighbor

I have two tables, `table_a` has polygons and the centroids of those polygons. `table_b` has another set of points overlaping the geometries in `table_a`.

For each row of `table_a` I need to find the point from `table_b` closest to the centroid of that row.

```
INSERT INTO nearest_node (nearest_drive_node) 
    SELECT osmid FROM london_drive_nodes 
    ORDER BY london_drive_nodes.geom <-> nearest_node.lsoa_centroid 
    LIMIT 1;
```

This returns

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "nearest_node"
  Hint: There is an entry for table "nearest_node", but it cannot be referenced from 
this part of the query.
```

I'm not sure exactly how to use the value from `table_a` as the point in the `ORDER BY` part of the query. The examples I've found are finding the nearest neighbor of a single point as a text string, rather than a column of points.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking for an update clause - where you set the `nearest_drive_node` based on the closest of the `london_drive_nodes` for that row?

Comment: yeah you're totally right. `UPDATE` not `INSERT` Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Inserting** the closest node as a new row in the table, without any other attribute, seems wrong. You most certainly want to **update** the existing records.

You must compute the closest node for each row of the input table, which can be achieve with a sub query.

```
UPDATE nearest_node
SET nearest_drive_node = (
  SELECT london_drive_nodes.osmid
  FROM london_drive_nodes
  ORDER BY nearest_node.geom <-> london_drive_nodes.geom
  LIMIT 1
);
```

If you were to just **select** (and eventually to insert this information in another table), you would rely on a lateral join:

```
select a.osmid,closest_pt.osmid, closest_pt.dist
from tablea a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT
     osmid , 
     a.geom <-> b.geom as dist
     FROM tableb b
     ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom
   LIMIT 1) AS closest_pt;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you reference `nearest_node` in the query, but not in the `FROM` clause, but in general, your query wouldn't work "for each row" anyway. Try combining `st_distance` and regular `min` with `group by` to get the minimum distance, then wrap it in a CTE or subquery to identify which node it actually is:

```
WITH distances AS (
    SELECT nn.id, nn.lsoa_centroid, min(st_distance(ldn.geom, nn.lsoa_centroid)) as min_distance
    FROM london_drive_nodes ldn, nearest_node nn
    GROUP BY nn.id
)
INSERT INTO nearest_node (nearest_drive_node)
SELECT ldn.osmid
FROM distances
JOIN london_drive_nodes ldn ON distances.min_distance = st_distance(distances.wgs84_centroid, ldn.wgs84_coordinates)
```

Comment: let's note that `st_distance` does **not** benefit from spatial indexes, while `<->` does.